# How to add the input text field in node view page

Tags: views, 7, entities, nodes

How can i add the field(input filed) for particular content type in submitted node view page.Using this field i can add some text to the particular node. Please suggest me is there any module for this or custom code.....

I think I've made it clear, please answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [editablefields](https://drupal.org/project/editablefields) module.

> This module allows CCK fields to be edited on a node's display (e.g.
>   at node/123), not just on the node edit pages (e.g. node/123/edit). It
>   also works within views etc. Anywhere a 'formatter' can be selected,
>   you can select editable (or click to edit).

You can  follow the below step for setting up editablefields for your content type.

- Go to  Administration -> Structure -> Content type
- Edit your content type and then click on "Manage Display"
- Change the Format to editablefields for your field.
- Once you set the formatter, you can click on the gear icon to further
  change the settings - the settings vary per field type

Comment: To use editablefields, you have to edit the content type under /admin/structure/types and then click the "Manage Display" next to the content type in question. Change the Format to editablefields. Once you set the formatter, you can click on the gear icon to further change the settings - the settings vary per field type.